# Configuring two touchpads with `synclient`

Tags: linux, synaptics-touchpad, magic-trackpad

I have two touchpads connected: the one built into my laptop and an Apple Magic Trackpad. I want to adjust some settings of the Magic Trackpad (`MinSpeed`, `MaxSpeed`, etc.) and the problem is that `synclient` adjusts settings of the built-in touchpad and doesn’t affect Magic Trackpad.

Sometimes it suddenly starts affecting the Magic Trackpad and not the laptop’s built-in one (I guess this happened when I connected Magic Trackpad *after* starting X, but I’m not sure).

Anyway, is there a way to *reliably* tell `synclient` which touchpad to configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of `xf86-input-synaptics` are configured through XInput2 properties, and synclient just emulates the old interface on top of that. (I *think* it just picks the first compatible device it can find.) Therefore you can use `xinput` instead:

```
$ xinput list-props "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
```

```
$ xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Synaptics Tap Time" 180
```

In case of identical device names, specify the numeric device ID instead.

Note that Xorg will soon migrate from the evdev+synaptics drivers to `xf86-input-libinput`, which is configurable *only* through XInput2 (and has slightly fewer settings, by the way).

```
$ xinput set-prop 11 "libinput Accel Speed" 1.0
```